# Creating QGIS Installer for Windows with GUI customization

Tags: qgis, installation, windows, gui

I'm trying to build a custom QGIS installer for Windows with a stripped down GUI. I customized the GUI using the customization function of QGis and saved it as a .ini file.

How can I include this custom GUI in my installer?

I found this very useful tutorial:

http://linfiniti.com/2011/05/building-custom-qgis-installers-for-windows/

and in the comments it also says that it's possible to include it using the customization tool. However, it doesn't exactly say how and where to save the customization file in the installer package.

Another possibility automatically load a custom GUI is explained here:

http://linfiniti.com/2011/07/batch-customizing-qgis/ Thought about exporting the registry    key customization.reg and to include it somewhere in the installer, but where?

So that would mean I would have to export the Windows registry key customization.reg, save it somewhere in the installation package and write a batch file that imports this registry key after the installation is finish.

Do you think that would be possible?

So that's what I have found out so far.

Does anybody have an idea what the easiest way would be to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So QGIS uses the [NSIS Installer System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) (aka Winamp Installer) that creates the final result.
Without trying, IMHO you need to work like this:

- checkout QGIS source
- build the windows binary
- add your .reg file to /ms-windows/installer files/
- Modify the .nsh script that it finds your .reg and patchs the registry that way
- Alternativly to last steps, use this way to add your custom settings:
  http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reg2Nsis_-_convert_registry_info_into_NSIS_commands

I highly recommend to use a Virtual Machine to as I expect you will need some time till it works fine and you should not mess up your system :)

I am not sure how this will influence the OS4win installer wrapper, as I expect you want to use it just on a few machines. (Maybe there is using the official installer and apply the .reg patch manually easier?)